# Is there a way to change the Input type Date format to ISO, i understand it is using OS local date format and displaying it?

Tags: typescript

Example:
Here is the input
`Date<input type="date" id="customDateInput">` [image]

I want to display in 'YYYY-MM-dd' format along with datepicker?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format